# Querying a database in Android causes duplicated data?

Tags: android, database, sqlite, duplication

I have an activity which has a database query and it brings back 300 records from the query.  Now I move to another activity and make changes in the same database.  Now when I return back to the first activity and refresh the database by making the *same* query, I get 600 records.

Can anyone please suggest where I am going wrong?

Comment: Without seeing your query or what happens in the other activity, it is not really feasible to guess what's going wrong.  Did you clear (reset? empty?) the in-memory result set when you went back to re-query the database?  If you restart the application, do you get 300 or 600 results from the query on the first pass?

Comment: Actually I realized its the UI, that tends to show this problem and not the Database query, the Results turn out to be 300 everytime, its just that the UI doesn't refresh the Data and keeps on adding to the previous Data.  Sorry for the hurry and not realizing the actualy scenario.

Comment: Seems that the issue wouldn't be with the Queries made by me, rather its dependent on the UI rendering pattern i have been following, the question has been put again for issue regarding the page curl animation which fails to render or refresh the given pages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems that the issue wouldn't be with the Queries made by me, rather its dependent on the UI rendering pattern i have been following, the question has been put again for Harism 
Thanks again everyone, helps everytime i am here, cheers!!